# Make server.R insert HTML code into webpage

Tags: accessibility, readability

I want to provide the UI a machine-readable version of my output.  How can I make server.R insert HTML code such as the following into the webpage UI.R dynamically generates?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> Favorite Color </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Jill </td>
    <td> pink </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Jenny </td>
    <td> purple </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is embarrassing...... Shiny already does what I was asking about...... I was just looking at the HTML code generated **when the page loads**, but there is more HTML code inserted into the existing HTML later. So there is no problem after all :)